# Group alternative values together in an Array

Tags: javascript

This is my URL: https://www.google.com/?Field1=A&Value1=A1&Field2=B&Value2=B1

and i have used the below script to get the query string:

```
var arr=[];
arr = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
```

which gives me the below output

```
["Field1=A", "Value1=A1", "Field2=B", "Value2=B1"]
```

but i would like to have the result as key value pair as shown below:

```
A: A1
B: B1
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Are the URL parameters always going to be in the correct order, or is parsing to get the index necessary?

Comment: `window.location.search`

Comment: @ZorroLearner _"would like to have the result as key value pair as shown below:"_ As string items within an array ; or object key , value pairs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the order of field and values to be same and field and value will always exist in pair.

Try following

```
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i=i+2) {

    obj[arr[i].split("=")[1]] = arr[i+1].split("=")[1];

}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: @ZorroLearner - Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function getUrlParams(url) {
    var ret = {};

    url
    .slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1)
    .split('&')
    .forEach(function(str){
        str = str.split('=');
        ret[str[0]] = str[1];
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
var urlParams = getUrlParams(window.location.href);
```

Having the URL: https://www.google.com/?Field1=A&Value1=A1&Field2=B&Value2=B1

`urlParams` should be equal to:

```
{
    "Field1" : "A",
    "Value1" : "A1",
    "Field2" : "B",
    "Value2" : "B1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\w+(?=&|$)/g` to match word characters that are followed by `"&"` or end of input string, `while` loop , `Array.prototype.shift()`

```js
var arr = "https://www.google.com/?Field1=A&Value1=A1&Field2=B&Value2=B1"
          .match(/\w+(?=&|$)/g)
, res = {};

while (arr.length) {
  res[arr.shift()] = arr.shift()
}

console.log(res)
```